# Rails CSS not loading with Ruby 2.0

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having an issue with loading CSS in my Rails app.  I have pulled the same repository on two machines.

On one machine, the CSS file is loaded correctly.  When I go to a page on this machine, I get the following in my terminal:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-06 19:03:32 -0500
Processing by HomeController#show as HTML
Compiled collaborators.css  (6ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled home.css  (145ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled patents.css  (0ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled projects.css  (64ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled users.css  (2ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled application.css  (308ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled jquery.js  (3ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled collaborators.js  (129ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled home.js  (0ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled jquery.1.8.2.js  (5ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled patents.js  (186ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled projects.js  (0ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled users.js  (0ms)  (pid 862)
Compiled application.js  (1185ms)  (pid 862)
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 13945 LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (95.7ms)
  Rendered home/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2088.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2114ms (Views: 2104.9ms | ActiveRecord: 8.3ms)
```

When I load the same page on another machine, I get the following in the terminal

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-06 19:31:19 -0500
Processing by HomeController#show as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 460 LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.4ms)
  Rendered home/show.html.erb within layouts/application (5.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 10.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

But none of the CSS compiles.  It also doesn't show up in the browser.  What could be the problem?

UPDATE: I ran rake assets:precompile on the second machine and it worked.  However, deleting the public/assets folder stopped it from working.  This means it was not live compiling.  Any idea why?

Comment: Do both machines have Ruby and Rails, and all of the gems involved installed and updated?

Comment: Yes.  The machine that doesn't work has Ruby 2.0.0.  The machine that does work has Ruby 1.9.3.  That's the only difference I see

Comment: Strangely. Running rake assets:precompile got the CSS loaded on machine 2.  But ONLY if I was running ruby 1.9.3.  With ruby 2.0, the assets would not load no matter what.  Is this a bug in ruby 2.0?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. but when Rails 4.0 comes out in the near future, be sure not to use different versions on your different machines.

Comment: can you show the contents of your application.css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whats  the content of you config/environments/development.rb

sepcifically --.

config.assets.compile = false/true ?

Comment: I set added this line and now the CSS and JS show up as they should on my second machine.  I'm still unclear as to why my first machine doesn't need this line, but the problem has been solved, thanks.

Comment: and how was this solved? as adding this line with true/false does not solve it

Answer (score 1):

I noticed some issues related to assets in ruby 2.0 as well, i.e.,  Applications running in 1.9.3 without problems having CSS issues.

Could you try to see if this helps:

Add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sprockets', '~> 2.9.0'
```

Then bundle install and try again...

Answer (score 0):

Is the second machine running in the `production` environment?  The CSS is only compiled in development.

Comment: the second is in development